# How to automount partition at startup or login?

Tags: automount

With my previous installation I just had

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sda2 && /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sda3
```

among the startup applications, but on my new installation (also 12.04.4) it has no effect.

The command works fine in the terminal.

Autostarting firefox using the startup applications tool works also.

How do I automount those partitions?

(No, update does not help!)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by saving the command into a file and registering that file in the startup applications window.